# Parse string with regex using ordered delimiters

Tags: ruby, regex, string, parsing, delimiter

I have a string of the following format:

```
University/Class (Term)
```

I need to split it into its three parts. I came up with `/\/|\s\(|\)/g` and that works really well for simple cases. Unfortunately, each of the three parts can contain those three delimiters. For instance:

```
University of StackOverflow (online)/Intro to asking questions (Fall2014)
```

The best solution (not perfect, I know) seems to be to write a regex that looks first for the `\/`, then the `\s\(`, and finally the `\)`, in that order. I've found some answers that seem to suggest answers but I've been thrown off by the mix of character and string delimiters in my case.

I'm definitely still working to understand regex in general so I would highly appreciate a well-explained solution. Thank you!

Comment: redit if the edit is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\/|\s\((?!.*\/)|\)(?!.*(?:\/|\s\())
```

Try this .Split by this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eZ0yP4/25

Or if you are willing to use groups the you can try this cn capture all ghe groups

```
(.*)\/(.*)\s\(([^\)]+)
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eZ0yP4/26

Comment: Thank you! Under what conditions should I be unwilling to use groups?

Comment: @ntdb if you dont have too many complex strings then you can split or else try groups

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
> "Universit­y/Class (Term­)".split(/­\s\((?!.*\()­|\)$|\//)
=> ["University", "Class", "Term"]

> "Universit­y of Stack­Overflow (onli­ne)/Intro to askin­g quest­ions (Fall­2014)".spl­it(/\s\((?!.­*\()|\)$|\­//)
=> ["University of StackOverflow (online)", "Intro to asking questions", "Fall2014"]
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest `scan` function instead of `split`

```
> "University/Class (Term)".scan(/.+(?=\/)|[^\/].*?(?=\s\()|[^()]+(?=\))/)
=> ["University", "Class", "Term"]
> "University of StackOverflow (online)/Intro to asking questions (Fall2014)".scan(/.+(?=\/)|[^\/].*?(?=\s\()|[^()]+(?=\))/)
=> ["University of StackOverflow (online)", "Intro to asking questions", "Fall2014"]
```

Comment: I didn't know about `scan`, thanks for pointing it out. Why would you prefer `scan` over `split` for this implementation?